# Phonegap XMLHttpRequest POST SOAP packet

Tags: web-services, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have a PhoneGap iOS app that I want to POST a SOAP packet to a web service and get a response. If I don't set a SOAPAction header, the POST works but server returns error because it expects a SOAPAction header.

If I do set a SOAPAction header, `onreadystatechange` never fires.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open ("POST", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST "+url+" HTTP/1.1");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    xhr.send ('SOAP here');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    //etc etc
```

Why would setting SOAPAction header completely kill the xhr, preventing onreadystatechange from firing?

Comment: You can register the `onreadystatechange` callback before any function gets called; add the line after creating `xhr`.

Comment: OK I put the `onreadystatechange` right after xhr creation, but `xhr.readyState` only ever gets to 1